# Not obvious differential equation (Riccati).

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a little problem with a differential equation:

$x' = 2x + x^2e^{t}$.

This is (if I'm not wrong) Riccati equation, so I can notice that $x(t) = -3e^{-t}$ satisfies the equation. Unfortunetely substitution $z=x+3e^{-t}$ doesn't reduce this equation to Bernoulli type. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

We must put $x=z-3e^{-t}$, as you did.

This gives us

$$z'+3e^{-t}=2z-6e^{-t}+e^t(z-3e^{-t})^2=2z-6e^{-t}+e^tz^2-6z+9e^{-t}$$

Therefore

$$z'=-4z+e^tz^2$$

Now we put $z=\frac{1}{u}$ to get

$$-\frac{1}{u^2}u'=-\frac{4}{u}+e^t\frac{1}{u^2}$$

This is $$u'=-4u+e^{t}$$

This one you know.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reduce this to a Bernoulli equation because it already is a Bernoulli equation.

You can solve by letting $z = x^{-1}$

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} - 2x = x^2e^t $$
$$ -x^{-2}\frac{dx}{dt} + 2x^{-1} = -e^t $$
$$ \frac{dz}{dt} + 2z = -e^t $$